# Datasource sitemap in Visual Studio

Tags: forms, web, datasource, sitemap

I have a problem in Visual Studio when I am trying to link a table to a data source. Whenever I run the web application, I always get the following **error**:

> The file web.sitemap required by XmlSiteMapProvider does not exist.

I am not entirely sure how to fix this since I am still a beginner in Visual Studio

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Answer (score 0):

It has already been resolved. I basically just created a sitemap and input all of the pages. I used this website to fix it.

[Linking sitemaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178426.aspx)